# Debugging iOS ad-hoc crash reports:

Tags: ios, ios4, crash-dumps

One of my users has sent me a bunch of crash logs, in which the majority of them read like this -

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33479466 objc_msgSend + 18
1   CoreFoundation                  0x33a770c6 __CFNotificationCenterDarwinCallBack + 18
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a5dbe0 __CFMachPortPerform + 204
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a556f8     __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a556bc __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47f76 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
6   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
7   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
8   GraphicsServices                0x33b0e4a4 GSEventRunModal + 108
9   GraphicsServices                0x33b0e550 GSEventRun + 56
10  UIKit                           0x32099322 -[UIApplication _run] + 406
11  UIKit                           0x32096e8c UIApplicationMain + 664
12  Nav                             0x00002ea2 main (main.m:14)
13  Nav                             0x00002e38 start + 44
```

This doesn't really make any sense to me, am I missing something really obvious?

Thanks, 
Teja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a wonderful blog post entitled [So you crashed in objc_msgSend()](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html). I strongly encourage you to read it. It should teach you how to find out what's going on here.